# Solr OR query does not return any result while queries returns result separately

Tags: solr, solr-query-syntax

I am trying to run OR query on Solr 6.6 like "field:[x TO *] OR -field:[* TO *]" which means greater than or equal some value or null. Even both field:[x TO *] and -field:[* TO *] has result sets individually this OR query does return empty set. When I use parenthesis like "(field:[x TO *]) OR (-field:[* TO *])" it returns the result of field:[x TO *] only. Can you explain me what the problem with this query here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is caused by the second part of your second statement (`OR -field:[x TO *]`). Think of the `-` operator as subtracting the second set from the first one - but the problem here is that you don't have anything to subtract the second set from.

When the `-field:foo` query is the *only* part of the query, Solr starts with the complete set of all documents, so that in a sense the query `*:*` (all documents) is prefixed to your query. When your query is later in a set of clauses, this isn't longer the case - it's only prefixed to the first clause (if at all).

To solve this, be explicit: `OR (*:* -field:[x TO *])`.